# Azure artifact - Maven project - GET request to download artifact failed

Tags: java, azure, maven, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to build a maven project which has its artifacts in an azure feed.

The command I'm using is `mvn clean install`

But there is an artifact which has .zip file in it. Previously it was working fine but all of a sudden due some unknown reason the build is failing with the following error message.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:unpack (unpack-artifact_name) on project project_name_Servers: 
Unable to resolve artifact. Could not transfer artifact com.project_name:project_name-support-maven-bom-artifact_name:zip:2.1 from/to 
Azure_artifact_feed (https://feed_URL/maven/v1): 
**GET request of: com/project_name/project_name-support-maven-bom-artifact_name/2.1/project_name-support-maven-bom-artifact_name-2.1.zip from Azure_artifact_feed 
failed**
```

The network and connectivity seems fine, as other artifacts are getting downloaded.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

- If you are working with `maven artifacts` in azure artifacts feeds you need to set up your feed first. Check below.
- You just need to add a `settings.xml` under `c:\users\<username>\.m2`
  It will be like **settings.xml**

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<servers>
<server>
<id>Suresh_Chikkam</id>
<username>****</username>
<password>****</password>
</server>
</servers>
<profiles>
<profile>
<id>azure</id>
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>central</id>
<url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
<releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
<snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
<id>azure</id>
<url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/YOUR_AZURE_DEVOPS_ORGANIZATION_NAME/YOUR_AZURE_DEVOPS_PROJECT_NAME/_packaging/YOUR_AZURE_ARTIFACTS_FEED_NAME/maven/v1</url>
<releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
<snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>
</profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
<activeProfile>azure</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

- Get the `<password>` Access token.

[image]

Click on `new token`.

[image]

After updating the above steps, maven-built success for me.

[image]

[image]

- You don't need to send a GET request to download artifacts from an Azure Artifacts feed in a Maven project. Maven handles downloading the artifacts for you as part of the build process, based on the configuration in your `settings.xml` file and `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Hi Suresh, I have done it already. The network and connectivity seems fine, as other artifacts are getting downloaded. How to fix this?

Other poms are getting downloaded except this one .zip artifact, so there seems to be no issue of pom.xml or settings.xml

Comment: I have rechecked from my end and it appears that the issue is based on the configuration that maven handles while downloading the artifacts.